# Yammer embed action (follow and like)

Tags: embed, yammer, social-media-like

Has anybody got the Yammer embed API for Follow and Like to work in a SharePoint site? I can get the buttons to appear and when I click on them they change to Liked and Followed but nothing is posted to Yammer and nothing appears in the activity feed. Several folks have tried this and given up and doing something via the Java SDK instead but this is long-winded with the embed API should work. Any ideas?

Code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
 <div id="embedded-like" style="width:400px;"></div> 
<script>
 yam.connect.actionButton({
 container: "#embedded-like",
 network: "mynetwork.com",
 action: "like"
 });
 </script>

<p>
 <div id="embedded-follow" style="width:400px;"></div> 
<script>
 yam.connect.actionButton({
 container: "#embedded-follow",
 network: "mynetwork.com",
 action: "follow"
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

don't know if you got there already - but was able to expand the object properties on the embed like to push details in the recent activity feed in yammer from a sp2010 page. Its totally hard coded for just one page - but I'm exploring the elements the like button can pick up - saw some on this page - but could be pre-API change

```
http://sp2013.blogspot.co.nz/2013/10/sharepoint-and-yammer-yammer-feed-like.html
```

my code:

```
<div id="embedded-like"></div>
<script src="https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
<script>         
    yam.connect.actionButton({
        container: "#embedded-like",
        network: "[mynetwork]",
        objectProperties: {
         url: "URL To my sp2010 page",
         type:  "page",
         title: "Some Title to show in the feed"
        },
        action: "like"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: FYI - the title can't be changed once that page has been initialized through someone clicking the like button for the first time. The title will be concatenated on a "user liked {title}" on the homepage of the users Yammer feed.